# Storage in Ionic not saving value into variables properly

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to send this.data as a parameter for the post request but when I put a console.log(this.data) before the return statement, it returns both token and regNo are null values but inside the then method of storage get, console.log(this.data) gives the correct value. What is going wrong here?

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { DiaryModel } from './diary.model';

@Injectable()
export class DiaryService {
  constructor(public http: Http, public storage: Storage) {}

    data: any = {token: null, regNo: null};

    getData(): Promise<DiaryModel> {
      this.storage.get('regNo').then((val) => {
            console.log(val);
            this.data.regNo = val;

          this.storage.get('user').then((val2) => {
              console.log(val2);
              this.data.token = val2.token;
          });
      });
      return this.http.post("http://www.mysite.xyz/services/service.php", this.data)
               .toPromise()
               .then(response => response.json() as DiaryModel)
               .catch(this.handleError);
    }

  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ionic works as a non blocking I/O model. In your code return statement will run before getting the value from storage methods. You have to make the storage methods and return statement synchronous so return statement wait until the storage method resolves the value.

```
getData(): Promise<DiaryModel> {
    return new Promise((resolve) =>{
        data: any = {token: null, regNo: null};

        this.storage.get('regNo').then((val) => {
            console.log(val);
            this.data.regNo = val;

            this.storage.get('user').then((val2) => {
                console.log(val2);
                this.data.token = val2.token;
            });
        });

        resolve(data);
    });
}

returnData(): Promise<any> {
    this.Data().then(res => {
        return this.http.post("http://www.mysite.xyz/services/service.php", this.data)
               .toPromise()
               .then(response => response.json() as DiaryModel)
               .catch(this.handleError);
    }
}
```

Then you can call the returnData() method to get the return statement.

Comment: It's still not working. Still got the same issue. Something else seems to be the issue.. :(

Comment: you forgot to return storage access promises.

Comment: @SurajRao how do i do that?

Comment: @ShafeefOmar did you try my answer?

Comment: @ShafeefOmar if you want this answer,add `return this.storage.get('regNo').then((val) => {` and `return this.storage.get('user').then((val2) => {`

Answer (score 0):

You need to chain the promises to get data *sequentially*. Since they are asynchronous.
Your http request is being sent *before* storage returns value.

I would do :

```
 getData(): Promise<DiaryModel> {
      let regPromise = this.storage.get('regNo');
      let tokenPromise =  this.storage.get('user');
      return Promise.all([regPromise,tokenPromise]).then(values=>{
         this.data.regNo=values[0];
         this.data.token = values[1].token;
         return this.http.post("http://www.mysite.xyz/services/service.php", this.data)
               .toPromise()
               .then(response => response.json() as DiaryModel)
               .catch(this.handleError);
    })
```